# Сайт лежит, и в то же время работает

Tags: php

Всем привет.

[Проверка работоспособности сайта](http://www.downforeveryoneorjustme.com/rutor.org)

Сайт rutor.org отлично открывается, однако, он не пингуется. То есть, запарсить что-то с него невозможно. Подскажите, почему так? И как можно спарсить с него информацию? (PHP, cURL)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ну ping и curl не особо связаны. Если не пингуется но открывается браузером то возможно и curl его сможет открыть (получить код, если точнее).

Если просто запрос курлом не сработает то пробуйте ставить хедеры. Очень часто на серверах есть проверки на хедеры вроде Referer или UserAgent. Если они не указаны или они не настоящие то и страницу сайт отдавать не будет.

В общем поиграйтесь с хедерами. Воспользуйтесь проксиками если что. Постарайтесь максимально сэмитировать обычный браузер.

Answer (score 2):

> однако, он не пингуется.

открываем `cmd.exe` и делаем `ping rutor.org` и видим что все прекрасно пингуется.

о чудо `file_get_contents('http://rutor.org/');` тоже работает!

В чем собственно был вопрос?

**UPD**

Имхо ТС ничего не сделал для того чтобы найти решение своей задачи кроме как проверил его работоспособность через левый сайт `abracadabra.com`

Comment: @Palmervan, я уже понял, в чем проблема, просто забанен айпишник.